# listBox Text Will Not Wrap

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to write a simple app that would parse a feedburner feed (in XML), extract data from the feed, scrub out some unnecessary data and then spit it out onto the screen.

I'm having difficulties wrapping the text in the listBox. I've spent the past few nights banging my head against the desk in an effort to get this to work. I've installed the Silverlight Toolkit and am trying to use WrapPanel, but it doesn't seem to want to work. The text displays fine in the listBox, I just can't seem to get the text to wrap.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

            <ListBox  x:Name="listBox1" Width="456" Height="646" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
    <Grid>
```

Here's the snippet of code that I'm using to add the items to the listBox:

```
StringReader stream = new StringReader(e.Result);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            string areaName = String.Empty;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "description")
                    {
                        areaName = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        areaItem = new ListBoxItem();
                        areaItem.Content = areaName;
                        listBox1.Items.Add(areaItem);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

***UPDATE***

I was able to get the text to populate the TextBlock by using this line:

```
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(areaName);
```

instead of this line:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(areaItem);
```

The only issue I seem to be running into now is the TextBlock not populating below the TextBlock area and not being scrollable.

***UPDATE 2***

Fixed this by removing the Height="x" line in the XAML. I am all set to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text in a TextBlock and turn on wrapping?

Inside your listbox:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the TextBlock suggestion. It wraps text just fine now, but only shows one entry. Here's the line I changed in the C#:  
textBlock1.Text = areaName; //areaName is the string

Comment: I think you should spend some time looking at the examples.  http://create.msdn.com/en-US

Comment: I've had to revert to using the listBox and still cannot for the life of me figure out how to wrap the text. 

I cannot use a textBlock to display the text as each element in the listBox MUST be selectable.